# Avoid extra line in laravel loop made by key numbers

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that generates excel file from my data like screenshot below

[image: onw]

There are 2 sets of issues here (yellow and blue)

Yellow: The columns should start from row #2 where it has `1` as `A2` value

Blue: My code somehow adds extra line for each data object which was `1` at first then became `2` and so on... *(so for each set of data it adds extra 2 empty rows)*

#### Code

here is my loop part that is in charge of printing data as you see in screenshot above:

```
$no = 2;
foreach ($br as $key => $value) {
    $no = $no + $key;
    $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$no, $key+1);
    $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$no, $value->va_number);
    $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$no, $value->customer_name);
    $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$no, $value->cabang);
    $sheet->setCellValue('E'.$no, $value->payment_date);
    $sheet->setCellValue('F'.$no, $value->payment_amount);
    $sheet->setCellValue('G'.$no, $value->br_no);
    
    $dtl = DB::table('bank_receive_dtl')
    ->join('inv','inv.id','=','bank_receive_dtl.inv_id')
    ->where('bank_receive_dtl.br_id','=',$value->br_id)
    ->select('bank_receive_dtl.*','inv.inv_no')
    ->get();
    foreach ($dtl as $key => $item) {
        $no ++;
        $sheet->setCellValue('H'.$no, $item->inv_no);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I'.$no, $item->payment_amount);
    }
    $no--;
}
```

The problem caused by `$no ++;` and `$no--;` in second loop where some of my objects have multiple invoice numbers as you see.

> PS: Here is what ideal final result should be look like `except coloring part :)`

[image: two]

**Can you point me to the part that I've made mistake?**

## Update

Yellow issue is solved by moving `$no ++` at the bottom like this:

```
$no = 2;
foreach ($br as $key => $value) {
    $no = $no + $key;
    $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$no, $key+1);
    $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$no, $value->va_number);
    $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$no, $value->customer_name);
    $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$no, $value->cabang);
    $sheet->setCellValue('E'.$no, $value->payment_date);
    $sheet->setCellValue('F'.$no, $value->payment_amount);
    $sheet->setCellValue('G'.$no, $value->br_no);
    
    $dtl = DB::table('bank_receive_dtl')
    ->join('inv','inv.id','=','bank_receive_dtl.inv_id')
    ->where('bank_receive_dtl.br_id','=',$value->br_id)
    ->select('bank_receive_dtl.*','inv.inv_no')
    ->get();
    foreach ($dtl as $index => $item) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('H'.$no, $item->inv_no);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I'.$no, $item->payment_amount);
        $no ++;   // <--moved down here
    }
    $no --;
}
```

Blue issue still remains.

Comment: This should come with a proper [mre] that includes the necessary sample data to reproduce the output.

Comment: _"Blue issue still remains."_ - is the `$no--;` after the loop still there now in your modified version, or was it removed?

Comment: @CBroe everything is same just moved `$no ++` (updated)

Comment: The "blue issue" would be due to `$no = $no + $key;` then, I suppose. 2 + 0 (key) for your first item gets you row 2, that is fine. After you output your 974/835 invoices for the second item, $no should now be 7 at the very end of the outer loop. Now comes your 3rd item, which will have key 2, which you again add to the current $no ... So you land in row 10 for your 3rd item, but it should be 9.

Comment: `$no = $no + $key;` should just be `$no = $no + 1;`, or directly `++$no`, I think, and initialized with `$no = 1;` before the loop.

Comment: Or you still initialize it with 2, but then _don't_ increase it at the start of your loop, _and_ also don't decrease it after the inner loop. Then the only thing that moves this line counter along by one, is the inner loop that outputs the invoices, and so you should automatically land in the correct row with your next item.

Comment: @CBroe sorry for late response, thank you it helped to fix the issue. appreciate it